# How to make checkboxes display checked on display

Tags: jsf, primefaces, initialization, selectmanycheckbox

I am using the following guide to implement many checkboxes into my tool:
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/manyCheckbox.xhtml

I have successfully done so, but what I want to happen is I want the checkboxes to be already ticked on display if a user has that role, and not checked if they don't. The idea being, an admin can check/uncheck which roles they want a user to have, with the ones they already have checked.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
<p:selectManyCheckbox id="roles" value="#{usersView.selectedRoles}" layout="grid" columns="3">
    <f:selectItems value="#{rolesView.roles}" var="role" itemLabel="#{role.name}" itemValue="#{role.name}" />
</p:selectManyCheckbox>
```

In my `usersView`, the `selectedRoles` is simply an `ArrayList` of all of the roles a user has.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just set the `selectedRoles`?

Comment: The 'selectedRoles' is set, when debugged I can see the list contains 2 elements, which relate to the two checkboxes I want to be checked, but they still render unchecked and I'm struggling to discover why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `selectedRoles` match the `itemValue` one by one on same order then Bingo your checkboxes will be auto checked

for ex:

`selectedRoles={'Mark','Jack'}`

and in your `#{rolesView.roles}` If you have the same `#{'Mark','Jack'}` as `#{role.name}` at the same order

Then simply, You got your self auto checked checkboxes.

Comment: Thank you, this cleared things up a little and helped me realise I was doing something stupid :)

Comment: @James Not at all , JSF is tricky for first time , But by the time she will teach you to do magic :)

Comment: Let me guess, you filled it with whole `Role` objects instead of `String` names?